# Footer or header in different language with php

Tags: php, footer, multilingual

I'm using the elxis cms to create a website. The site is in two languages, English and Russian. I want in the index.php to have some html code in footer which will be different for each language. For example I will show my address and contact information and I want it to show in English if the site visitor choose as his language the English. 
I wonder is there any php code to that?
something like

```
<?php 
        if ($lang=en {
            echo '< footer in english>

        if ($lang=ru {
            echo '< footer in russian> ?>
```

I have seen on an xml file a code which look like

```
<col lang="en"><![CDATA[.....]]></col>
```

Is there something equal for php??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a URL which looks like this:

`http://Example.com/index.php?lang=en`

for the english site, and this:

`http://Example.com/index.php?lang=ru`

for the russian site,

Then use some php like this:

```
<?php 
    if($_GET["lang"] == "en"){
        echo '<footer in english>';
    elseif($_GET["lang"] == "ru"){
        echo '<footer in russian>';
    };
?>
```

I used this on my website and for me it worked well.

p.s. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Hi Goudgeld1, thank you for your answer. my footer content looks like <section id="footer">
    <div class="....
<?php 
   $flex->footerMods();
   
   if ($eDoc->countModules('footer') > 0) {
    
    $eDoc->modules('footer', 'none');
    
    
   }
?>
                    </div>
                </div> 
when i use your code from above I get a white page, maybe I'm not doing something correctly. Any suggestions on how I should add my code to yours..

Comment: I dont know the rest of your code but mabey you can use something like this: `<?php
 if($_GET["lang"] == "en"){
  echo '<section id="footer"><div>';
  $flex->footerMods();
  if($eDoc->countModules('footer') > 0){
   $eDoc->modules('footer', 'none');
  }
  echo '</div></section>';
 }elseif($_GET["lang"] == "ru"){
  echo '<section id="footer"><div>';
  $flex->footerMods();
  if($eDoc->countModules('footer') > 0){
   $eDoc->modules('footer', 'none');
  }
  echo '</div></section>';
 };
?>`  Wow that looks messy, but copy and paste it in your code editor and try.